# how many users in a GAE instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, instance

I'm using the Python 2.5 runtime on Google App Engine. Needless to say I'm a bit worried about the new costs so I want to get a better idea of what kind of traffic volume I will experience.

If 10 users simultaneously access my application at myapplication.appspot.com, will that spawn 10 instances?
If no, how many users in an instance? Is it even measured that way?

I've already looked at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html but I just wanted to make sure that my interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Users" is a fairly meaningless term from an HTTP point of view. What's important is how many *requests* you can serve in a given time interval. This depends primarily on how long your app takes to serve a given request. Obviously, if it takes 200 milliseconds for you to serve a request, then one instance can serve at most 5 requests per second.

When a request is handled by App Engine, it is added to a queue. Any time an instance is available to do work, it takes the oldest item from the queue and serves that request. If the time that a request has been waiting in the queue ('pending latency') is more than the threshold you set in your admin console, the scheduler will start up another instance and start sending requests to it.

This is grossly simplified, obviously, but gives you a broad idea how the scheduler works.

Answer (score 1):

First, no.

An instance per user is unreasonable and doesn't happen.

So you're asking how does my app scale to more instances? Depends on the load.
If you have much much requests per second then you'll get (automatically) another instance so the load is distributed.
That's the core idea behind App Engine.